# How can I get the checkbox element value from a submission handler?

Tags: 8, forms

I have a single checkbox field. When I try to get its value in a submission handler, the value I get is always 0 whether it has been selected or not.

```php
/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
  $form['item_specifics'] = [
    '#type' => 'checkbox',
    '#title' => t('Sync item specifics'),
    '#attributes' => [
      'name' => 'field_item_specifics',
    ]
  ];
    
  $form['fieldset_item_specifics'] = [
    '#type' => 'fieldset',
    '#title' => $this->t('Item Specifics'),
    '#attributes' => [
      'class' => ['form-wrapper', 'js-form-wrapper'],
    ],
    '#states' => [
      'visible' => [
        ':input[name="field_item_specifics"]' => ['checked' => TRUE],
      ],
    ],
  ];
    
  $form['submit'] = [
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => $this->t('Sync'),
  ];
    
  return $form;
}
```

How can I get the checkbox value from a submission handler?

Comment: If I remove the attributes key and just use the default name value for the state on the other field it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of setting `$form['item_specifics']['#attributes']['name']` to `'field_item_specifics'`, you need to set it to `'item_specifics'`.

```php
/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
  $form['item_specifics'] = [
    '#type' => 'checkbox',
    '#title' => t('Sync item specifics'),
    '#attributes' => [
      'name' => 'item_specifics',
    ]
  ];

  $form['fieldset_item_specifics'] = [
    '#type' => 'fieldset',
    '#title' => $this->t('Item Specifics'),
    '#attributes' => [
      'class' => ['form-wrapper', 'js-form-wrapper'],
    ],
    '#states' => [
      'visible' => [
        ':input[name="item_specifics"]' => ['checked' => TRUE],
      ],
    ],
  ];

  $form['submit'] = [
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => $this->t('Sync'),
  ];

  return $form;
}
```